# Python Xlib issue

Tags: python, wxpython, xlib

I have a small python app using the Xlib package. I am not sure how to create a window/app properly to be managed by a window manager. Everytime I set the DISPLAY to xorg, the window is automatically created and mapped. However, the X11 window manager denies the mapping, but the window is still shown. It doesn't respond to keyboard input but will still change the cursor once the mouse moves into the window.

```
self.screen = display.Display().screen()
self.window = self.screen.root.create_window(
                    10, 10, 100, 100, 1,
                    self.screen.root_depth,
                    background_pixel=self.screen.white_pixel,
                    event_mask=X.ExposureMask | X.KeyPressMask)
self.window.map()
```

If I create an app/frame with WXPython the mapping works correctly, however, I am unable to set the X11 Font cursors in wxpython ... this is why I'm using Xlib.

So ... I either need a way to set the X11 font cursors in wxPython or a way to properly setup the self.window above in XLib.

Comment: What exactly is the wxPython error you get?

Comment: There is no WXPython error ... I simple don't know if/how you can instruct wx to display the font cursors in X11 ... I do know that you can display the X_spraycan as wx has a default cursor with that particular one. But you can't select any of the 76 or so X11 font cursors.